# Are the following size rules taken from the herediarily finite world consistent with ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

Let $x^*$ be the set of all cardinalities that are strictly larger than the cardinality of $x$ and strictly smaller than the cardinality of $P(x)$. Formally, that is:

Define: $s=x^* \iff \forall y (y \in s \leftrightarrow \exists k (|x| < |k| < |P(x)| \wedge y=|k|))$

Are the following rules consistent with ZFC? if so, what's their consistency strength?

$\forall x (|x|>2 \to |x| < |x^*| <|P(x)| )$

$\forall x (|x|>2 \to ||x|^{+*}| > |P(x)|)$

$\forall x \forall y (|x| > |y| \wedge |y|>2 \to |x^*| > |P(y)|)$

Where $|x|^+$ is the successor cardinal of the cardinality of $x$.

Where cardinality $``||"$ is defined in the customary manner after Von Neumann's.

Also for better reading the above rules can be written in terms of cardinals as:

$\forall \kappa \, (\kappa >2 \to \kappa < |\kappa^*| < 2^\kappa )$

$\forall \kappa \,(\kappa >2 \to |(\kappa^+)^*| > 2^\kappa)$

$\forall \kappa \,\forall \lambda\, (\kappa >  \lambda >2 \to |\kappa^*| > 2^\lambda)$

Where $``<",``>"$ are the known cardinal inequalities; and $\kappa^*=\{\lambda\mid \kappa < \lambda < 2^\kappa \}$

Comment: The "set of all cardinalities that are..." means "any set with cardinality that..."? If yes, the first is vacuously true.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla, let me give an example, take $x$ to be a set whose cardinality is 3, then x* would be the set {4,5,6,7}, so x* is the set of all cardinalities that are strictly larger than 3 and strictly smaller than 8.

Comment: Maybe relevant :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483349/on-the-continuum-hypothesis-only-finitely-many-cardinals-between-aleph-0-and.

Comment: If your theory is consistent, it has quite high consistency strength as it implies a massive failure of SCH: If $\kappa$ is a strong limit then $2^\kappa\geq\aleph_{\kappa^+}$. If it is inconsistent, the singular cardinals are the troublemakers. Using Eastons theorem, one can construct a model where your theory holds on the regular cardinals. Your theory implies that all strong limit cardinals are $\aleph$-fixed points, which prevents one from applying e.g. Galvin-Hajnal to get an inconsistency.

Comment: By the way, maybe more people would consider your question if it was phrased more conveniently. For example, your third axiom already implies the second one. Moreover this is only about cardinal arithmetic, so why not talk directly about cardinals instead of the cumbersome notation $\vert x\vert$?

Comment: Zuhair, I re-edited the last few lines to use $\kappa,\lambda$ (the variables we usually use to represent cardinals) rather than $\alpha,\beta$ (which would suggest ordinals and may result in misunderstandings).

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasLietz, thanks for the suggestion, I've done it. But as regards the third axiom, yes it implies the second, but my question is about the consistency strength of the addition of each rule to ZFC, and then about the addition of more than one rule of them to ZFC, and at last about the addition rule 1 and 3 to ZFC.